# Remote Servlet Comms

Tags: java, servlets, communication

I have two servlets A & B.
On B i intend to have a a method isAvailable() which A will call to check the status. If this method returns true then im going to pass it an object to B.

On doing a bit of reading i'm seeing a couple of options non of which im that familar with.  JNDI with remote EJB , RMI or simple HTTP (not sure how youd do the last)

What do you guys think ? Any other options ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make use of the fact that your infrastructure is already talking HTTP ?

So servlet A can perform an HTTP GET on a particular path to check a status (either sending back an object or checking an HTTP response code - this latter method seems a misuse of status codes, however), and PUT/POST an object if required. I note that you're running across multiple hosts, and this will work in your scenario.

The objects can be serialised using standard Java, or via a representation such as XML - perhaps serialised using [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org)).

That would seem to me a pretty straightforward way to leverage off the infrastructure you have.

Answer (score 0):

Are your servlets running in the same application server? If so, you might like to use [Spring](http://springframework.org) to inject B into A so that the method can be called directly.

Even if the servlets are running in different containers, you can expose them (using Spring again) as `Remote` objects and similarly inject B into A (except that this will mean that the Spring container will inject a proxy for the remote object). This has zero footprint in your code (i.e. it's all defined by config files and  Spring takes care of everything for you)

Comment: There is one instance of Servlet A on a master host and many of Servlet B each on its own host with its own tomcat instances.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this isAvailable() method in Servlet B accesses some kind of "global" data which is stored in the Servlet. Could you extract this object to a separate Singleton which then is available for both Servlets?

Comment: I was thinking isAvailable() basically checks the CPU overhead on this particular host (servlet). If its able to accept the job it will respond with a true / or a certain HTTP response code.

Comment: Why does isAvailable() have to be implemented in the Servlet class then? I would moved it into a common "service layer" package.

Comment: True True .. mjustin. How might I call this from my Parent Servlet ?

Answer (score 0):

> *There is one instance of Servlet A on a master host and many of Servlet B each on its own host with its own tomcat instances.*

You can use `java.net.URLConnection` to programmatically fire a HTTP request. You can find [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) a simple tutorial.

Let A fire a HTTP request to B and have in B a servlet which listens on those requests and returns the response accordingly. This can be a simple `response.getWriter().write("ok");` or so. You can even return a XML string and so on. In A you can then read this value from the `InputStream` of the `URLConnection`.